# ASP.NET website - changing the value entered in a form before submitting

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I have a form in a .aspx file in a Visual Studio project. I have a variable that I want to change the value of before the user hits the submit button. I cannot figure out how to do this in Visual Studio. I am new to Visual Studio and when I am developing for Android, it is easy: just make the changes in the OnClick method.

I created a function in the code behind and I have that as the event handler for the submit button. The problem is, when the submit button redirects, the value is unchanged.

Field:

```
<input type=hidden name="AMOUNT" value="<%=amount%>">
```

Submit button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnComplete" type="submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submitted" />
```

Submitted function:

```
protected void Submitted(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    amount += 1;
}
```

The "amount" variable is 100 and is displayed as 100 on the next page instead of 101.

Comment: try to pass the value of amount variable in a querystring when you redirect to the next page

Comment: where do you initialized `amount=100`

Comment: try storing your variable as session variable with `Session["amount"] = amount` after you increment the `amount`. Also you should retrieve incremented value from `Session["amount"]` on `Page_Load`

Comment: @JaydipJ I initialize it in Page_Load

Comment: @ctumturk I put 'Session["amount"] = amount' in the line after I increment 'amount' but on the next page it still appears as 100. As for retrieving it on 'Page_Load', I'm trying to do it on the Submit button click, not when the page loads.

Comment: is your variable static ?

Comment: @Mainak No, it's declared as `protected string amount;`

Comment: since when does a string have its value incremented ? it should either be integer or decimal.

Comment: @Mainak you are right. I don't know how I didn't notice that. I'm surprised I didn't get an error. I changed it to the following code: `        int amountInt = Int32.Parse(amount);
        amountInt += 1;
        amount = amountInt.ToString();`
It still shows up as 100

Comment: When you click on button, it increments amount by 1 and when renders output it displays 101 instead of 100

Comment: @PiyushKhatri I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean to say that when you check page first time, you will see 100, correct? And once you click on button it will be incremented by 1 and you will see 101, is it happening correct?

Comment: @PiyushKhatri No. I see 100.

Comment: Have you debug and checked whether btn click event is executing or not?

Comment: I think the problem could be that it is a hidden field.

Comment: @Questioner, are you binding the value to the hidden field in `Page_load` ?

Comment: @PiyushKhatri I am not sure how

Comment: @Noobie I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: This seems like such a simple thing to do. In Android programming it's extremely straightforward. I must be going about this entirely wrong. Can anyone point me in the direction of a tutorial that would explain how to do this? I've googled but haven't found anything. Basically all I want to do is be able to do something with the form data before it's sent off to the target URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just posting to the same page, checking post data and changing the value before sending it off to the other URL.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it is working fine. I suggest you debug your page with F11 to see which line changes your variable value.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnComplete" type="submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submitted" />
<input  name="AMOUNT" value="<%=amount%>" />
```

And;

```
protected int amount = 100;
protected void Submitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["amount"] != null) amount = (int)Session["amount"];
    amount += 1;
    Session["amount"] = amount;
}
```

Comment: You said you declared the variable as `protected string amount;` and still you haven't received any error messages with `amount +=1;`. It makes me wonder if there is a `int amount = 100;` line in your code?